# How to compose T-SQL WHERE statement to determine whether the specific filter value is a power of 2 collectible from column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm

I got SQL Table and column called MultiTypes (int).
MultiyTypes column values are regular numbers. I need to decompose those numbers to power-of-2 collectibles and then to check whether the filter value is one of these collectibles.

How to construct my WHERE Statement properly?

Example: 
Column has values:

```
10 which is (8+2), 
25 which is (16+8+1), 
17 which is (16+1), 
101 which is (64+32+4+1)
```

I want to build query

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE @FilterValue -???-> MultiTypes
```

-???-> means - @FilterValue is one of the "power-of-2" collectibles of the iterated value

If filter value is 8, I will get rows with MultiTypes values 10 and 25
If filter value is 1, I will get rows with MultiTypes values 17, 101 and 25

Comment: You need to use the bit shift operators, but the exact syntax would depend on the actual SQL database you are using.  "SQL" is just a language, not an actual product, so tell us which database you are using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.).

Comment: Like Tim said. Alternatives include doing a bitwise AND or just relying on integer division and modulus. At least the latter should work in all major RDMSs. WHERE (MultiTypes / @flag) % 2 = 1

Comment: Using MS SQL. Edited.

Comment: @P.Petkov . . . I am a bit baffled on what your data looks like and what you want returned for a result set.  What is the filter value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know if a filter value matches a bit-array in the "1" positions, you use bitwise-and.  It looks like:

```
where MultiType_Column & @filter = @filter
```

There is no need to decompose the value to specific types.

If you want to know if *any* of the values are set, then you can use:

```
where MultiType_Column & @filter <> 0
```

Comment: Ok, I thought it wont work, but checked it with C# and it seems works... Probably syntax is different in MSSQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter based on the `type(k)` (`2^k`), you can use `&` operator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE (MultiyType_Column & (POWER(2,k)) <> 0
```

The above query gets all rows which have `type(k)`. Fo example if `k=3`, to get all rows that have `type3` you can do the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE (MultiyType_Column & (POWER(2,3)) <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally to test if `MultiTypes` matches the combination of types, say `Type2` + `Type4` we do, pseudocode:

```
(MultiTypes <bit AND> (Type2 <bit OR> Type4)) == (Type2 <bit OR> Type4)
```

`<bit AND>` , `<bit OR>` are sql product specific, check your product's manuals.

Sql-server demo

```
declare @multitype int = 128 + 16 + 1;
declare @test int = 128 + 1;
declare @test2 int = 64 + 1;

select 'Yes, @multitype includes all types of @test' res
where @multitype & @test = @test;


select 'this will not return any row' res2
where @multitype & @test2 = @test2;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this cannot be resolved in a SQL query because the lack of arithmetic operations you can make in the query, my recommendation is to create a procedure and there you can divide the number the times that you need.